# Add database data in HashSet to fill SelectItem

Tags: jpa, collections, primefaces, filtering

I have the method above to fill a Primefaces 4 filterOption dataTable column:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{item.prefDep}" filterOptions="#{upbController.prefDepItems}" >
```

I'm already using HashSet to avoid repeated values, but it's not clear for me why it loads all data from database column and renders a gigantic combo filled with repeated values.

Can someone help?

The method in the managed bean:

```
public Set<SelectItem> getPrefDepItems() {
    Set<SelectItem> setList = new HashSet<>();
    setList.add(new SelectItem("", "Options..."));
    for (Upb id : getPrefDepsList()) {   
        setList.add(new SelectItem(id.getPrefDep()));
    }
    return setList;
}
```

The method in Abstract Controller:

```
public List<T> getPrefDepsList() {
    if (prefDeps == null) {
        prefDeps = this.ejbFacade.findPrefDeps();
    }
    return prefDeps;
}
```

The method in Abstract Facade:

```
public List<T> findPrefDeps() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

The namedQuery in the Entity Bean:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Upb.findPrefDeps", query = "SELECT DISTINCT u.prefDep FROM Upb u")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you implemented correctly the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods in your entity?

Comment: Yes. But, sorry, what do you meant doing this question?

Comment: Where are you invoking the named query?

Comment: Hi. In the managed bean above.

Comment: I see that you are creating a criteria query, but I don't see any reference to the named query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in the 
    **setList.add(new SelectItem(id.getPrefDep()));**
as the set will see each SelectItem as a different one(I guess the equals method doesn't compare the values, just the SelectItem address)

the solution is to change the **getPrefDepsList** method to return a Set of T, or Upb, as you're using, or do something like:

```
public Set<SelectItem> getPrefDepItems() {
    Set<SelectItem> setList = new HashSet<>();
    setList.add(new SelectItem("", "Options..."));

    Set<Upb> setPrefDeps = new HashSet<>();
    setPrefDeps.addAll(getPrefDepsList());
    for (Upb id : setPrefDeps) {   

        setList.add(new SelectItem(id.getPrefDep()));
    }
    return setList;
}
```

Also be sure to have the equals and hashCode into Upb.